# How does my hand amplify an FM radio signal?

Tags: electric-circuits, everyday-life, radio

I have a gizmo that broadcasts an FM radio signal from my phone's headphone socket to my car's radio antenna.

Sometimes, there's another station on the same frequency with a stronger signal and my car plays that signal instead. However I've noticed that if I hold my hand up near the transmitter, my signal takes over again.

What's going on when this happens? Am I somehow boosting the signal with my hand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not boosting the signal; you're either acting as a reflector (capturing a bit more of it to feed to the antenna) or blocking a competing source, or perhaps a bit of both.

By analogy, when you hold your hand to your ear to help you hear something, your hand is acting a reflector for sound waves to direct a little more energy into your ear. It can also keep out other extraneous sounds coming from other directions.

Our bodies contain a lot of water and other chemicals which makes them fairly electrically conductive. Any electrically conductive material can serve as either an antenna or a radio-reflective element. So, the position of your body relative to the radio antenna will affect its reception.

Comment: I've observed that people can alter the tuning, not just reflect or block.

Comment: @Anthony X  What else could act as a reflector?  Can I cover my transmitter with something to improve the signal?

Answer (score 11):

A human body may reflect and absorb radio frequencies, though not very efficiently. It may as well act as a resonance chamber for certain frequencies. For a signal of 100 MHz, the involved wavelength is 3 m, and so it is possible that parts of your body are acting slightly as a resonant chamber. (for an optimal resonance, you should have 1.5 m diameter, too many cheeseburgers...)

You might be surprised if you have a look at the amazing [Lydia Kavina](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn4TgYkqdi8) and other [theremin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin) players videos around. This instrument is played without any physical contact, by merely doing hand movements near the antennas. The human body acts itself as a part of an L-C circuit.

[image]

Comment: I cannot resist adding a couple of additional amazing links: another [Lydia Kavina](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDAKIqysMz0) performance, and a curious [amateur thereminist playing The Beatles in front of M51](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3EPtUPcs8s)