# How can a skull/head works as an 'amplifying' antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism

When you hold your remote control to your head it seems that the reach of that remote control is longer. But how does precise work.

It is only working with radiowaves, not infrared. But how can a head or skull make the signal better. Are those radiowaves going in your head and than reflect to give a parabola to focus more. If so, why are those waves not going (bend) around your head as the wavelength would be large.

Or does your head support in a totaly other way?

In a similar question, there are mainly two ways of explaining this. First our head function as a resonance chamber and second there is magnetically coupling from our head/body with the remote control antenna.
But if our head is a resonance chamber how can this work? As the radiowaves has to go inside our head and then going out with larger reach. I don't understand how em-waves can get larger reach to use a resonance chamber. 
And what is exactly meant with magnetically coupling is that the same as the resonance coupling?

Comment: I would think that the matter in your skull has some finite electrical conductivity at RF frequencies, and so your skull (or just about any other object) placed close to an RF antenna will affect its RF signal characteristics for either the better or the worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101913/.

Comment: Ok, the other answers seems still a bit unclear, but I will adapt my question.

Comment: Without some reasonably accurate and reproducible experimental data, this question is going to be really hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

That observation may be related to other factors such as the directionality of the receiving antenna. Generally a head or a bag of water absorbs and blocks RF. It could be cleaning out some interference, I suppose. You could try tests with a bottle of coke and from other directions.